GWT No source code is available for type elemental2.dom.Element; did you forget to inherit a required module?
I'm trying to get a div element with ID="calendarJS" and pass it to a constructor.
import elemental2.dom.Document;
import elemental2.dom.Element;
.
.
.
Element calendarEl = new Document().getElementById("calendarJS");

After loading the page the GWT compiler shows this error:
.
.
.
[ERROR] Line 133: No source code is available for type elemental2.dom.Element; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Line 133: No source code is available for type elemental2.dom.Document; did you forget to inherit a required module?
.
.
.

What do I miss?
I have the elemental2-promise, elemental2-dom and elemental2-core in my pom.xml

As the error says, did you forget to inherit the module in your .gwt.xml file? Adding it to the pom isn't enough.
You need to have
<inherits name="elemental2.dom.Dom"/>

in your .gwt.xml file to specify that you will use those sources.

Hi Colin,
sure I did forget!!
Thanks a lot for your time .. much appreciated!!
